# Creating a memory buffer without malloc

Tags: c

I am working on an embedded system (ARM Cortex M3) where I do not have access to any sort of "standard library". In particular, I do not have access to `malloc`.

I have a function `void doStuff(uint8_t *buffer)` that accepts a pointer to a 512 bits buffer. I have tried doing the following:

```
uint8_t buffer[64] = {0};
doStuff((uint8_t *) &buffer));
```

but I'm not getting the expected results. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any alternative approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doStuff(buffer)` shall be ok since `buffer` **is already** an `uint8_t*`.

Aside of this, you're closing one bracket too much after `&buffer` in your example.

---

If `buffer` is of variable size, you should pass the size into `doStuff` too, if it's of constant size, I'd also pass the size just in case that you change the size one day.

This being said, you should do it the following way:

```
uint8_t buffer[64] = {0};
int     len        = 64;
doStuff(buffer, len);
```

Answer (score 1):

a simplemalloc(): have a char mem[MAXMEM]; and a struct freetable. Then write your own simplemalloc(), that finds in freetable a big enough junk of memory, and returns the offset into mem. simplefree() would then adjust the freetable.

EDITH:

if you need a lot of malloc()s, you may even devide your static mem into different chunks for different tasks (one chunk for exactly 100byte allocs, one fort the size of your favorite struct, and so on) this will speed up finding free mem.

if you are short of mem, you should implement a bestmatch() in simplemalloc(), which as a bad sideeffect slows the execution down.

if you have enough memory, you can implement a debugversion, which "allocates" a bit more memory and puts XXX before the start and after the end of the simplemalloc()ed mem. on free() you can check, if this XXX is broken, so you know you have some buffer-over or under-flow, which you can be aware of.